# How do I skip a column entry on INSERT when a value is blank in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting lots of rows into a database and some of the columns are blank **for some of the rows**.

How can I insert without assigning a dummy value to these blank fields?

```
       1 INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 5, 'anotherValue')
       2 INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName',  , 'anotherValue')
       3 INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 2, 'anotherValue')
       4 INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 9, 'anotherValue')
```

My problem lies in row 2 where there is a blank value in between city name and another value. Ideally, I'd like the value to remain null.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to fix the source queries. e.g. b y replacing all `,  ,` with `, null ,`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Just add null. Perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just tell it to insert a null:

```
    INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 5, 'anotherValue')
    INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', null , 'anotherValue')
    INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 2, 'anotherValue')
    INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 9, 'anotherValue')
```

Answer (score 20):

You should always explicitly specify which columns you're inserting to - then you can leave out those you don't want:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Leads(Col1, Col2, Col4) VALUES('name', 'cityName', 'anotherValue')
```

(leaving out `Col3` here in this example)

Comment: I agree with this approach too.

Comment: +1 for always specify columns, but this won't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to find these fields and insert a NULL. The regular expression /,\s*,/ should identify the gaps. If you're running a linux/mac try:

```
perl -pi -e 's/,\s*,/, NULL,/g' path/to/file.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method you can use:

```
INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 5, 'anotherValue')
INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', DEFAULT, 'anotherValue')
INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 2, 'anotherValue')
INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName', 9, 'anotherValue')
```

This would also work for columns that have default values and\or columns that you can't insert a value to (like TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `null` if there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

For Insert statements
Use Values(Null,...) if field accepts Null

Use Values('',...) if field has (,not null) requirement,and for fields where you do not want Null to display e.g. a Note field.

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem with an existing application that worked in prod but not on a fresh local install.

Mysql had to be configured like this :

```
sql-mode=MYSQL40
```

and then it will accept row like :

```
 INSERT Leads VALUES('name', 'cityName',  , 'anotherValue')
```

Comment: The question is about [tag:sql-server], not MySQL.