# Can't send the value of null to MySQL database using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, null

I'm trying to send `null` to my MySQL database using Node.JS:

```js
con.query("INSERT INTO Routes (routeTrigger) VALUES ( " + null + " )", {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

But when looking in the database, the updated value reads `'null'`. The database's `NULL` is supposed to read **`NULL`**. If I send capital `NULL` instead, that doesn't even work (in Node.JS). If I send `'NULL'` it sends the string "NULL", and not the database's `NULL`.

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation to build your queries, ever.  It's just a bad habit that will open you to SQL injection hacks when you make production stuff.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript's `null` is not the same as SQL's `Null`. You want (in your case, using raw SQL strings) a string:

```js
con.query("INSERT INTO Routes (routeTrigger) VALUES ( null )", {title: 'test'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

But note that that creates a row that's entirely `null`. Which is possible, but it's unlikely what you want.

What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately it's not to much help. See my comment on the answer below and I think what I want will get more clear for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign the **NULL** value In the **SQL** tables, you can think differently.

Instead of assigning **NULL**, you can tweak the field (column) so that the *default value* (when no value is assigned) is : **NULL**.

Now, when you insert your new row, just **don't assign any value to that field**.

---

Example :

Let's say the table is structured like so :

**MyTable**

> **id**: auto increment; ...
>
> **name**: text
>
> **url**: text; default = NULL

Then you could do:

`INSERT INTO Mytable ( name ) VALUES ( "Joe" );`

As you omit the **url** information, it gets set to **NULL**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I realize this. But the truth of the matter is that the query will sometimes have more or less data to send (and thus assign). I must therefore make sure that the query handles all eventual variables, since they come from user input.

Comment: Yes I understand, maybe you can change the **title of your question** for [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691184/how-do-i-skip-a-column-entry-on-insert-when-a-value-is-blank-in-sql). But you know, usually, it's a simple mistake on your side (in the code) that causes this issue. Try to `console.log( query )` and see what your query looks like.

Answer (score 1):

To pass null value in mysql using nodejs, we need a different kind of implementation of a query.

```
conn.query({
    sql: `INSERT INTO project values(?, ?, ?, ?);`,
    values: [projectId, name, startDate, endDate]}, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error executing sql: ", error.message);
            return res.send(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Official site says: "undefined / null are converted to NULL"
and it works.

Use that above syntax to fire a query.

Answer (score 0):

This was used for PostgresQL table migration from JSON using Node.js; may help. Check the values coming from your source, and if it doesn't exist for that column, use "NULL" with double quotes. EG, if it's JSON:

```js
const makeVal = (val) => {
    if (val === undefined) {
        return "NULL"
    } else {
        return "'" + JSON.stringify(val).replace(/'/g, "''") + "'" 
    }
}
```

See this gist https://gist.github.com/foureyedraven/ca90a7dcbfd0918c153b0c91ec9317c5 for full implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Node [mysql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) I was able to insert a null value by doing the  following:

```
let myValue = null;
```

Note the column configuration:

`'myValue' varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score -1):

*it worked*

```js
if (my_var != null) {
    my_var = '"' + my_var + '"';
}                             
else {
    my_var = "NULL";
}
connection.query('insert into my_table(my_var) values(' + my_var + ')', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: That's not SQL-Injection proof at all. Do not take this guy's advice!

Comment: that code worked for me, can you please explain why this is not a sql injection ?

Comment: The code works totally fine, but hacking your database works aswell with that code.