# Could this string concatenation in my query result in injection attacks?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46105771/cant-send-the-value-of-null-to-mysql-database-using-node-js#comment92954195_46105771) made me worried that the way I am searching my databases may result in an injection attack. Bellow is the query I'm currently using:

```
return db.query("SELECT * FROM customers 
                 WHERE ( num LIKE ? AND name LIKE ? )", 
                [customer.num + "%", customer.name + "%"], callback)
```

Should I be adding the *%* symbol in my call to the API, or how would this be properly implemented?

Comment: The comment seemed to be about another query and the comment was valid for that query. It does not apply to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment you're referring to uses string concatenation, whereas you are using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

This means that the intention is that the `db.query` function should be applying filtering and escaping to the inputs you provide, and *hopefully* they would be fairly extensive, and protecting you well.

It doesn't mean that you're *immune* to SQLI attacks, because there are just *so many* of them, but you have followed good practices in using prepared statements.

To check and/or improve your security against SQLI attacks, you could:

- Audit the database connector library you are using to see whether it has known issues.  `npm audit` is your friend here
- Consider using another system for the queries, like an ORM like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/), which tend to use querying systems even further separated from the actual SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No, you misunderstood it. The problem comes when you concatenate a string with the SQL Query . e.g `db.query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE ( num LIKE "+ var +"AND name LIKE "+ var2+" )"`. You are safe here because you are using placeholders that will escape them.